# Error con base de datos sqlite en android

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

Tengo este código para gestionar una base de datos sqlite en android:

```
public class ConfiguracionSQLite extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public ConfiguracionSQLite(Context context) {
        super(context, "configuracion", null, 1);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE configuracion (id_configuracion INTEGER, contenido TEXT)");
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    }

    public void inicializarTabla() {
        SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
        db.execSQL("INSERT INTO configuracion (id_configuracion) VALUES(1)");
        db.close();
    }

    public Vector<String> comprobarTabla() {
            Vector<String> result = new Vector<>();
            SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
            Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM configuracion", null);
            while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                result.add(cursor.getString(0));//id_configuracion
                result.add(cursor.getString(1));//contenido
            }
            cursor.close();
            db.close();
            return result;
    }
}
```

Hasta aquí todo bien. El problema viene cuando añado un campo mas a la tabla:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE configuracion (id_configuracion INTEGER, contenido TEXT, contenido_2 TEXT)");
}

public Vector<String> comprobarTabla() {
        Vector<String> result = new Vector<>();
        SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM configuracion", null);
        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            result.add(cursor.getString(0));//id_configuracion
            result.add(cursor.getString(1));//contenido
            result.add(cursor.getString(2));//contenido_2
        }
        cursor.close();
        db.close();
        return result;
}
```

Si desinstalo la aplicación y la vuelvo a instalar, no hay problema, pero si lo que hago es una actualización, entonces tengo un error aqui: `result.add(cursor.getString(2));//contenido_2`

¿Cómo puedo hacer para que cuando realice una actualización también se actualice la base de datos sqlite?

Este es el log del error:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 1, col 2 from
>   CursorWindow.  Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before
>   accessing data from it.

Comment: Que actualizacion realizas en tu bd?

Comment: Me refiero a actualización de la app @diegoveloper

Comment: Puedes poner el log de error que te aparece

Comment: ya esta @diegoveloper

Comment: Ok, es probable que al instalar tu app solo habias creado 1 campo para esa tabla, y lueho agregaste 2 columnas mas a tu tabla, cierto? Tambien veo que en inicializarTabla solo insertas un campo, los demás estarían nulos. Prueba desinstalando y volviendo a instalar tu app y nos cuentas si sigues con error

Comment: Si desinstalo y vuelvo a instalar no me pasa el problema, es solo si la actualizo. ¿Hay alguna forma de solucionarlo? @diegoveloper

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cada vez que cambies alteres alguna tabla de tu base de datos es necesario que incrementes el número de version de base de datos en tu AndroidManifest o build.gradle depende como este configurado.

No te olvides tambien de modificar la alteración de tu table en tu metodo oCreate de Sqlite para los que instalan tu app por primera vez.

Luego de eso, para los que ya tenian instalada tu app antes de la alteracion de datos, la aplicación entrará al siguiente método:

```
      @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int  newVersion) {

         }
```

Ahí debes escribir tu script para alterar tu tabla (añadir nuevo campp, etc)

Para más info: [https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html#onUpgrade(android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase, int, int)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html#onUpgrade(android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase,%20int,%20int))

Comment: Y en el campo `oldVersion` que tendria que poner el `número de version`?

Comment: Nada, es solo para que compares que número de version de bd tienes, ya que segun eso se haran querys distintas segun sea el caso